# "Cannot reindex from a duplicate axis" when groupby.apply() on MultiIndex columns

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, pandas-groupby

I'm playing around with computing subtotals within a DataFrame that looks like this (note the MultiIndex):

```
        0   1   2   3   4   5
A   1   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
    2   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
B   1   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
    2   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

I can successfully add the subtotals with the following code:

```
(
    df
    .groupby(level=0)
    .apply(
        lambda df: pd.concat(
            [df.xs(df.name), df.sum().to_frame('Total').T]
        )
    )
)
```

And it looks like this:

```
            0   1   2   3   4   5
A   1       0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
    2       0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
    Total   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
B   1       0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
    2       0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
    Total   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

However, when I work with the transposed DataFrame, it does not work. The DataFrame looks like:

```
    A       B
    1   2   1   2
0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
3   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
4   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
5   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

And I use the following code:

```
(
    df2
    .groupby(level=0, axis=1)
    .apply(
        lambda df: pd.concat(
            [df.xs(df.name, axis=1), df.sum(axis=1).to_frame('Total')], 
            axis=1
        )
    )
)
```

I have specified `axis=1` everywhere I can think of, but I get an error:

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

I would expect the output to be:

```
    A               B
    1   2   Total   1   2   Total
0   0.0 0.0 0.0     0.0 0.0 0.0
1   0.0 0.0 0.0     0.0 0.0 0.0
2   0.0 0.0 0.0     0.0 0.0 0.0
3   0.0 0.0 0.0     0.0 0.0 0.0
4   0.0 0.0 0.0     0.0 0.0 0.0
5   0.0 0.0 0.0     0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Is this a bug? Or have I not specified the axis correctly everywhere? As a workaround, I can obviously transpose the DataFrame, produce the totals, and transpose back, but I'd like to know why it's not working here, and submit a bug report if necessary.

The problem DataFrame can be generated with:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.zeros([6, 4]),
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], [1, 2]])
)
```

Comment: In my opinion it is bug.

Comment: What's your expected output for that?

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: @piRSquared I'm using version 0.19.2. I'll update and see if that helps.

Comment: @Allen I would expect the output to be the transpose of the working output, with subtotals along rows.

Comment: @bdforbes, can you please add your expected output in the question?

Comment: @piRSquared I still get the problem with pandas 0.20.2.

Comment: @Allen I've added the expected output.

Comment: This has been submitted as a bug report at https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16646